# Extract a table from the Oracle database using R

Tags: r, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to extract a table from Oracle database using R by giving the date condition

Following is the code that I run in R:

```
pw14.db.train<-sqlQuery(myconn,"select * from r_input where snapshot_date <='16-01-2015'")
```

But I get the following error:

```
[1] "HY000 1843 [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-01843: not a valid month\n"                                     
[2] "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'select * from r_input where snapshot_date <='16-01-2015'
```

The date format for snapshot_date col. on the database table is "23-07-14".

What should be the correct query that I need to write when using the date column?

Comment: That error indicates that snapshot_date is a DATE column, therefore it has no "date format".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the character string '16-01-2015' into date type since your column on Oracle is of date type:

```
pw14.db.train <- sqlQuery(myconn,"select * from r_input where snapshot_date <=  to_date('16-01-2015', 'dd-mm-yyyy') ")
```

and then your query will work correctly.